# Why so many redirects in spam email URL?

Tags: email, http, url-redirection, spam

A new spam email arrived today with a URL in it:

```
http://agreementpoint.cricket/Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO
```

It redirects many times before it completes reaches its final page.

I am sort of wondering why? After all I can follow the entire sequence of redirects, so they are not hiding anything... from me.

I followed the redirects using my C program that does an HTTP GET, which I revised to imitate the ability of browsers to look for A tags in 302 redirect pages and follow them, when the "Location:" header is missing as is the case here.

*If spam filters don't follow the redirects, why is anyone paying for spam filtering?*

Anyway for this spam message, the resulting long series of redirects, is amusing:

```
bash-3.2$ ./get http://agreementpoint.cricket/Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO
URL=http://agreementpoint.cricket/Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO
IP resolved to 66.228.35.10
DOMAIN: agreementpoint.cricket
IPv4: 66.228.35.10
REST OF URL: Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO
REQUEST: GET /Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO HTTP/1.1
Host: agreementpoint.cricket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: identity
Referer: agreementpoint.cricket/Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO
Connection: close

REQUEST LENGTH 333, ACTUALLY SENT 333
GOT CHUNK 536 BYTES
TOTAL BYTES RECEIVED: 536
RECEIVED:
___________________________________________
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 17:03:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Location: i.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD/OKDDyDDhDO/iKOXO
Content-Length: 310
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="i.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD/OKDDyDDhDO/iKOXO">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at agreementpoint.cricket Port 80</address>
</body></html>

RESPONSE CODE: 302
URL=http://agreementpoint.cricket/i.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD/OKDDyDDhDO/iKOXO
IP resolved to 66.228.35.10
DOMAIN: agreementpoint.cricket
IPv4: 66.228.35.10
REST OF URL: i.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD/OKDDyDDhDO/iKOXO
REQUEST: GET /i.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD/OKDDyDDhDO/iKOXO HTTP/1.1
Host: agreementpoint.cricket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: identity
Referer: agreementpoint.cricket/i.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD/OKDDyDDhDO/iKOXO
Connection: close

REQUEST LENGTH 345, ACTUALLY SENT 345
GOT CHUNK 310 BYTES
TOTAL BYTES RECEIVED: 310
RECEIVED:
___________________________________________
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 17:03:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Location: http://74.208.164.141/r.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO==17q55h5jmnl9jmz3q93d5m@xyzAuzusxzsxt@wBrv
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


RESPONSE CODE: 302
URL=http://74.208.164.141/r.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO==17q55h5jmnl9jmz3q93d5m@xyzAuzusxzsxt@wBrv
DOMAIN: 74.208.164.141
IPv4: 74.208.164.141
REST OF URL: r.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO==17q55h5jmnl9jmz3q93d5m@xyzAuzusxzsxt@wBrv
REQUEST: GET /r.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO==17q55h5jmnl9jmz3q93d5m@xyzAuzusxzsxt@wBrv HTTP/1.1
Host: 74.208.164.141
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: identity
Referer: 74.208.164.141/r.php?Q1U7E0r7l2OpXBD-OKDDyDDhDO-iKOXO==17q55h5jmnl9jmz3q93d5m@xyzAuzusxzsxt@wBrv
Connection: close

REQUEST LENGTH 415, ACTUALLY SENT 415
GOT CHUNK 316 BYTES
TOTAL BYTES RECEIVED: 316
RECEIVED:
___________________________________________
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 17:03:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.42
Location: http://www.lnksecure26.com/rd/r.php?sid=9500&pub=202510&c1=120090030112031020200000001559193296460961&c2=&c3=
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


RESPONSE CODE: 302
URL=http://www.lnksecure26.com/rd/r.php?sid=9500&pub=202510&c1=120090030112031020200000001559193296460961&c2=&c3=
IP resolved to 64.71.235.16
DOMAIN: www.lnksecure26.com
IPv4: 64.71.235.16
REST OF URL: rd/r.php?sid=9500&pub=202510&c1=120090030112031020200000001559193296460961&c2=&c3=
REQUEST: GET /rd/r.php?sid=9500&pub=202510&c1=120090030112031020200000001559193296460961&c2=&c3= HTTP/1.1
Host: www.lnksecure26.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: identity
Referer: www.lnksecure26.com/rd/r.php?sid=9500&pub=202510&c1=120090030112031020200000001559193296460961&c2=&c3=
Connection: close

REQUEST LENGTH 427, ACTUALLY SENT 427
GOT CHUNK 376 BYTES
TOTAL BYTES RECEIVED: 376
RECEIVED:
___________________________________________
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 17:03:47 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: uid9500=1362582916-20170213090347-00e5225facfe7f80be971e74e6be97f3-; path=/; domain=lnksecure26.com
Location: http://bromilt.com/198024fa95c9ed6800/202510/120090030112031020200000001559193296460961/1362582916
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


RESPONSE CODE: 302
URL=http://bromilt.com/198024fa95c9ed6800/202510/120090030112031020200000001559193296460961/1362582916
IP resolved to 5.255.64.228
DOMAIN: bromilt.com
IPv4: 5.255.64.228
REST OF URL: 198024fa95c9ed6800/202510/120090030112031020200000001559193296460961/1362582916
REQUEST: GET /198024fa95c9ed6800/202510/120090030112031020200000001559193296460961/1362582916 HTTP/1.1
Host: bromilt.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: identity
Referer: bromilt.com/198024fa95c9ed6800/202510/120090030112031020200000001559193296460961/1362582916
Connection: close

REQUEST LENGTH 405, ACTUALLY SENT 405
GOT CHUNK 444 BYTES
TOTAL BYTES RECEIVED: 444
RECEIVED:
___________________________________________
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 17:03:47 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: uid3825=555863914-20170213110347-9d3794996387fe0fe8a4dc97077f3c73-; expires=Thu, 16-Mar-2017 16:03:47 GMT; path=/
Content-Length: 165
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="http://agorafinancial.cake.aclz.net/?E=TV4IHEar%2bGfZZ8ABzPP4XA%3d%3d&s1=470402&s2=555863914&s3=202510"</script>
RESPONSE CODE: 200
bash-3.2$ exit
```

FYI, 74.208.164.141 is an IP for 1and1's servers.

One domain is in California, where spamming is presumably illegal.

```
 Tech Organization: CAKE MARKETING
 Tech Street: 20411 SW BIRCH ST. STE. 250
 Tech City: NEWPORT BEACH
 Tech State/Province: CA
 Tech Postal Code: 92660
 Tech Country: US
 Tech Phone: +1.9495482253
 Tech Email: DOMAINS@CAKEMARKETING.COM
```

If you go to the website CAKEMARKETING.COM, index.html is a 404 error.

I revised my C program to look for literal Javascript redirects, adding yet more redirects from this spam URL:

```
    URL=http://agorafinancial.cake.aclz.net/?E=TV4IHEar%2bGfZZ8ABzPP4XA%3d%3d&s1=470402&s2=555878517&s3=202510
    IP resolved to 198.254.67.203
    DOMAIN: agorafinancial.cake.aclz.net
    IPv4: 198.254.67.203
    REST OF URL: ?E=TV4IHEar%2bGfZZ8ABzPP4XA%3d%3d&s1=470402&s2=555878517&s3=202510
    REQUEST: GET /?E=TV4IHEar%2bGfZZ8ABzPP4XA%3d%3d&s1=470402&s2=555878517&s3=202510 HTTP/1.1
    Host: agorafinancial.cake.aclz.net
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: identity        Referer: agorafinancial.cake.aclz.net/?E=TV4IHEar%2bGfZZ8ABzPP4XA%3d%3d&s1=470402&s2=555878517&s3=202510
    Connection: close

    REQUEST LENGTH 413, ACTUALLY SENT 413
    GOT CHUNK 631 BYTES
    TOTAL BYTES RECEIVED: 631        === RECEIVED: ===
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Location: https://agorafinancial.cake.aclz.net/?E=TV4IHEar%2bGfZZ8ABzPP4XA%3d%3d&s1=470402&s2=555878517&s3=202510&ckmguid=ebb014a1-d8a8-4d97-940c-9433c5d02915
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 17:36:31 GMT
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 281

    <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
    <h2>Object moved to <a href="https://agorafinancial.cake.aclz.net/?E=TV4IHEar%2bGfZZ8ABzPP4XA%3d%3d&amp;s1=470402&amp;s2=555878517&amp;s3=202510&amp;ckmguid=ebb014a1-d8a8-4d97-940c-9433c5d02915">here</a>.</h2>
    </body></html>

    RESPONSE CODE: 302
    SECURE URL=https://agorafinancial.cake.aclz.net/?E=TV4IHEar%2bGfZZ8ABzPP4XA%3d%3d&s1=470402&s2=555878517&s3=202510&ckmguid=ebb014a1-d8a8-4d97-940c-9433c5d02915
    Error.
    bash-3.2$ <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
    <h2>Object moved to <a href="https://pro1.agorafinancial.com/617426">here</a>.</h2>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: That's typically how advertisement delivery and especially real time  bidding for ad space works today. See also http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-serving/diagramming-the-ssp-dsp-and-rtb-redirect-path/. And it's not really a security question unless the delivered ad is malicious (i.e. malvertisement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technique of filtering spam (malware, phishing, etc) mail is looking up URLs (more commonly just the domain names) that are in the message (typically against a URLBL, using DNS, like a DNSBL).

If the real destination is only found after redirects, then the one in the message will not be found with a simple lookup. This is particularly the case if the redirect service provides legitimate content as well. The filtering system can follow the redirects as well, but (a) is generally limited in time so may not follow until the end of a long chain, and (b) it is more difficult to follow a redirect that isn't a 301 or 302 response (e.g. using JavaScript).

In addition, sometimes the links are redirects simply because of the business model (allowing tracking and so on).

Comment: If they don't follow the redirects, why is anyone paying for spam filtering? That's like an auto mechanic who doesn't pull out an air filter to see if it's dirty. It's a trivial task. Why are 25-year-olds getting paid $100,000 for not doing their jobs? The JS code case may not be easy, granted, except in the literal URL case for which my own code scans. But the literal URL case is proven to exist in the wild. And the full JS processing should be done anyway to look for JS-based attacks like XSS.